# Php Does not loop, provides only one item in the other page, edit

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

Edited: My first problem was solved, but another problem came up, only one user id is provided. So here is the screenshot of the revised code.

[image]

[image: My table]

Going back to the table, The user will press edit button, so he can edit the problem and give appropriate action..

My code for the table above is this:

```
<form action="edit.php" method="get">
                            <?php

                $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM complaints");

                    echo "<table border='1'>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Id Number</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Problem</th>
                    <th>Date Reported</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>";

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td name=id_number>" . $row['id_number'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td name=remarks>" . $row['remarks'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td name=status>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td name=date>" . $row['date_reported'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . "<INPUT TYPE = Submit Name = Submit1 VALUE =Edit>" . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
                    echo "</table>"; ?> </form>
```

My code for the edit.php is this: [for the user id part]:

```
User ID: <input type='text' disabled='disables' name='userid'placeholder='<?php


                $userid = $_GET["userid"];


                    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM complaints WHERE id_number = '$userid'", $link);

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
                    {
                    echo $row['id_number'];

                    }


            ?>'></br>
```

Now, I am having difficulty, on the user id part, because only one user id show which is the 201010005 id, and the user id to be shown is the one in line with the edit that has been pressed by the user.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to make each row a different form, and the action should contain `?id=$row[id_number]`, so that the server script can retrieve the appropriate row.

Comment: You can also use `$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM complaints WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");` in conjunction with `ASC` or `DESC` or using the PDO method `$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` and the row name(s) you wish to show.

Comment: Note: You need to change this `<INPUT TYPE = Submit Name = Submit1 VALUE =Edit>` to this `<INPUT TYPE = 'submit' Name = 'Submit1' VALUE ='Edit'>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the id of the user that you are going to edit, so in the form add another input, but hidden with the id value, like this:

```
echo "<td>" . "<INPUT TYPE = hidden Name = userid VALUE = " . $row['id_number'] . ">" . "</td>";
```

Then in the edit page you´ll grab the user and set the query with the WHERE conditional like this:

```
$userid = $_GET['userid'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM complaints WHERE id_number = '$userid'");
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, it provides only one user id in the edit page, but only one user id which is the 201010005,

Comment: I added your suggested code, and it looks like this `echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td name=id_number>" . $row['id_number'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td name=remarks>" . $row['remarks'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td name=status>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td name=date>" . $row['date_reported'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . "<INPUT TYPE = Submit Name = Submit1 VALUE =Edit>" . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . "<INPUT TYPE = text Name = userid VALUE = " . $row['id_number'] . ">" . "</td>";
     echo "</tr>";`

Comment: and for my edit.php `User ID: <input type='text' disabled='disables' name='userid'placeholder='<?php
     $userid = $_GET["userid"];
     echo $userid;
     $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM complaints WHERE id = '$userid'");
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo $row['id_number'] . " " ;
      } 
   
    ?>'></br>`

Comment: sir, need some more help

Comment: It seems like you have an error on the query, you have:
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM complaints WHERE id = '$userid'");

It should be:
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM complaints WHERE id_number = '$userid'");

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM complaints WHERE id = XXX");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
print_r($row);
```